# Como listar objetos de uma deteminada classe?

Tags: delphi, orientação-a-objetos

Para exemplo, digamos que possuo uma classe `TConfiguracao`.

Aqui os atributos construtores e destrutores

e em alguns formularios eu crio varias variaveis do tipo TConfiguracao

```
conf1 :TConfiguracao;
conf2 :TConfiguracao;
...

conf1 := TConfiguracao.Create();
conf2 := TConfiguracao.Create();
...
```

No fechar deste formulário eu faço:

```
FreeAndNil(conf1);
FreeAndNil(conf2);
```

Esta funcionando 100%. O que eu gostaria de saber é, existe alguma maneira de percorrer todos os objetos dessa classe `TConfiguracao` e aplicar um `FreeAndNil` sem saber ao certo quantas variáveis desse tipo eu criei? Sei que existe uma maneira de percorrer os componentes de um *form* dessa maneira

```
for i := 0 to Form.ComponentCount - 1 do
  begin
    if Form.components[i].classtype is  TEdit then
    begin
      //
    end;
  end;
```

Mas objetos de outras classes não consigo. Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso??

Comment: Essa é uma classe criada por você?

Comment: sim, a classe foi criada por mim.. nao coloquei ela inteira para facilitar o entendimento ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supondo uma classe e um tipo de exempo:

```
TMyClass = class
private
    FIndex : Integer;
public
    //Crio um novo tipo TMyClassArray que representa um array dessa nova classe.
    type TMyClassArray = array of TMyClass;  
    // Crio uma variável de nome Instances que não vai fazer parte dos objetos criados, mas sim da classe. 
    // E por isso deve ser chamada atraves do identificador da classe. 
    class var Instances : TMyClassArray; TMyClass. 
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy;
    //Else code...
end;
```

E seu construtor:

```
constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
    inherited;
    SetLength(Instances, Length(Instances) + 1);
    FI := Length(Instances) - 1;
    Instances[FI] := Self;
    //Else code...
end;
```

E seu destruidor:

```
destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
var
    I : Integer;
begin
    //Else code...
    Instances[FI] := nil;
    I := FI;
    while(I <= Length(Instances) - 1)do
    beign
        Instances[I] := Instances[I + 1];
        Instances[I].FI := I;
        Inc(I);
    end;
    SetLength(Instances, Length(Instances) - 1);
    inherited;
end;
```

Poderás acessar `TMyClass.Instances` no seu código para obter todas as instâncias já criadas.

Nota 1: Talvez o destruidor precise de um melhor manejamento de memória.

Nota 2: A convenção dita que `Instances` seja uma `class property` e não `class var` como eu a descrevi apenas por praticidade.

Comment: vou realizar uns testes pesquisar um pouco e e tentar entender melhor o seu exemplo.... 

type TMyClassArray = array of TMyClass;
class var Instances : TMyClassArray;


nao estou familiariazado com INSTANCES..... pouco tempo de OO :(

assim q realizar os testes posto aqui...

ja agradeco a atencao e a ajuda...

Comment: `Instances` é só o nome que eu dei pra variável.

Comment: uhmmm entendi... certo certo.... ja estou conseguindo acessar os objetos.. agora so preciso dar uma polida no destroy...

Comment: No `destroy` atual o objeto já se apaga da lista de instâncias, mas não reduz o tamanho do _array_, que vai só crescer a cada novo objeto de `TMyClass` criado.

Comment: isso mesmo... funcionou certo aqui, o problema é q se tiver umas 3 instancias
posicao 0 - A
posicao 1 - B
posicao 2 - C

se eu remover o indice 1 e diminuir o tamnho do array e depois disso add outro ele vai add  na posicao 2 q esta ocupado pelo "C"... estou certo???

Comment: @FelipeSachetti Se você apenas diminuir sim. O certo seria trazer para trás os elementos após a lacuna. E depois diminuir. Vou editar a resposta com isso.

Comment: perfeito, fiz todos os testes e ajustes com base nas ideias q me passaste, PERFEITOO... precisei so fazer uma alteracao em relacao ao q vc postou, antes de incrementar o i no destroy TMyclass(Instances[i]).FI := i; para atualizar o FI das instancias...  mto mto obrigado mesmo...

Comment: Editei com a alteração que você falou. Se funcionou pode aceitar a resposta. =)

Answer (score 2):

O que você pode fazer é utilizar um **TObjectList**.
Você deve instanciar o TObjectList e depois pode ir adicionando seus objetos nessa lista através do método **Add**.
Quando destruir o TObjectList **todos os objetos adicionados ao mesmo serão destruídos também.**
A propriedade OwnsObjects do TObjectList deve estar True(Default) para que seja possível destruir os objetos.
Para destruir você também pode usar o Delete, Remove, ou o método Clear também.*
*Obs.: Você tem que adicionar a unit **Contnrs** na uses.*

Comment: pois é @wesleyluan eu ate pensei e fiz uns teste com TObjectList o problema é que para isse eu teria q passar em todos meus formulario criando essa lista, pois em casa um deles tem instancias de uma classe com diferentes atributos... entao ficaria meio trabalhoso... acabei optando pela de criar uma array na classe pois assim eu so preciso fazer a chamada do destroy das instancias a partir do formulario padrao... sendo q os demais forms herdam esse form.... mas obrigado pela dica...